# Is it approprate to use System.Exception in this situtation? 

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, exception

Normally it frowned upon to use System.Exception but I am wondering if this is my only choice.

I have this scenario

1. User requests task for editing
2. Permission checks are done.
3. If all is good task row from db is retrieved
4. A update to the task is then committed and updates the column to say it is locked.
5. Some timezone stuff gets applied to this task to convert dates to local time.
6. Task is displayed to user.

So if anything happens between steps 1 to 4 the task is still good as it is not locked. However if it fails on step 5 and I cannot display the task to the user the file is locked and will be locked until a scheduled job runs to ensure that files locked to long are forced to be unlocked.

That kinda is not ideal as it could have been some temporary fail and the next time they request the file it could work again. But now they have to wait(same with all other subscribers) X minutes till it auto unlocks.

So my first thought was use a finally statement but this always gets run no matter what so I was unable to figure out how to say well the file is now locked don't bother unlocking it.

Or the file is locked but something went wrong unlock it. It would be nice if C# had a statement that ran only when an exception happened.

So my only other thought is have an Exception that if anything happens it will unlock it in there. The only case it would not is if it is an SQl Exception since no point trying to unlock something if the database is down.

Of course I would use elmah to log the error and slowly add better exception types as they would occur.

So does anyone have any better ideas?

Comment: since when is it frowned upon to use exceptions?

Comment: it's frowned upon to have exceptions drive your logic, imo, not overall

Comment: @ Jean-Bernard Pellerin - It not frowned to use Exceptions but frowned to just always use "Exception()" for everything.

Comment: @Marc - I don't really think it is driving my logic it is just an outcome that can happen and I should be prepared for that. If you have a better way then wrapping it in a generic Exception I am all ears and rather do that.

Comment: @chobo2, I see, i took your first sentence to be 'exceptions' not `System.Exception`

Comment: C# does have a construct declaring code that will only be run in case of exceptions -> catch{}. The use of it is debatable though

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't let perfect become the enemy of good. Catching a general exception is perfectly fine in this scenario. If you can catch and recover from more specific exception types, do it. But having a everything-just-went-to-hell recovery plan is not just okay but laudable.

Answer (score 2):

Catching `System.Exception` is acceptable if it is the top of a thread and you don't want your program to crash under any circumstances.  In general, catching `System.Exception` is a bad idea because you should have some idea of what kind of errors might occur, such that when somethin completely unexpected happens, it bubbles up to the top of your thread where you catch `System.Exception` and possibly provide the stack trace info etc for debugging purposes.

In your case, since you are worried about 'something bad' happening in step 5, which deals with timezone conversions, you can try to anticipate which specific exceptions or classes of exceptions might fire there, and specifically catch those, handle the unlock appropriately.

Alternatively, since you apparently have the ability to create said scheduled task which finds locked files and effectively forces an unlock, can't you use that same logic in your finally block? e.g. if it is locked, unlock it, otherwise, noop.